# Prefix added to my cookie name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, cookies

I am using Codeigniter PHP Framework with Tank Auth authentication library. In my config file, I have `$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';`.

**Problem:** After logging in, I checked for the cookie using Chrome's developer tools and found that instead of `ci_session`, it is `something_ci_session` where `something` prefix was automatically added in. This is the same prefix added to all my databases automatically by my web host.

I wonder if its related to the web host, and how I can remove the prefix. Thanks!

Comment: _"This [cookie prefix] is the same prefix added to all my databases automatically by my web host."_ Enough to open a ticket and ask your hoster, if you ask me. ;-)

Comment: So, what is `something` precisely? This might give a clue as to where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web host has to add this prefix in order to keep your app from conflicting with someone else's app if they should choose the same `sess_cookie_name` value of `ci_session`.

You can't remove it.

The method of sharing they're using is that all of their customers on a given machine are using the same instances of server apps, rather than unique virtual machines running unique services.